# Automating Report Writing with Microsoft Office

Tags: pdf, forms, ms-word, report

I write compliance reports for work.  I fill in a PDF form and click 'Yes' or 'No' to indicate whether the company is in compliance with a particular statute.  I would like to have this form autopopulate my compliance report in Word with the company's name and the appropriate findings and corrective actions. Is this possible? If not, can I achieve this using other Microsoft Office applications? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but PDF viewer itself cannot run arbitrary code for security reasons. If you organize things with certain conventions, then, after you make a change to PDF, you can save it, and then run another script which would then do what you want. I would recommend Python as the scripting language.

Please tell us more about your compliance reports - are they currently open as you change stuff? Can they be re0built from scratch or only updated with relevant changes?

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=17259,18168,26637,26792&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=python+read+pdf&cp=13&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&aq=f&aqi=g4g-o1&aql=&oq=python+read+p&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=5a996d56de453056

http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/173/284/